# Ways to create a singleton with private variables?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton, private

I'm trying to create a singleton that has variables not directly mutable from the outside. This is my current code:

```
var singleton = new (function () {
    var asd = 1;
    this.__defineGetter__("Asd", function() {
        return asd;
    });
})();

alert(singleton.Asd) // test
```

However, it seems like alot of ugly code just to achieve a simple thing.

What are some cleaner alternatives to create a singleton with such *private* variables?

Comment: I don't see any object literal...

Comment: Private static properties... I don't get it.

Comment: @Alnitak, Was messed up with the terms, the object *instance* I meant.

Comment: @Rudie, It's alike VB.NET and C#'s `readonly` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only closure can bring real private variable in JavaScript. Usually we use some kind of naming convention to tell if the variable is private.

```
var TheStaticClass;

(function () {
  var a=1;
  TheStaticClass.__defineGetter__("A", function() {
    return a;
  });
})();

alert(TheStaticClass.A) // test
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var theStaticClass = (function () {
    var a = 7;
    return { get A() { return a; } };
})();

console.log(theStaticClass.A);
```

Comment: @Kooilnc, how do I remove the error for IE9? What's wrong with the code?

Comment: you can't. IE doesn't support getters/setters. The `__defineGetter__` syntax is also a nogo with IE

Comment: @Kooilnc: Thank you, I have modified the code. It appears that we don't need getters in the first place for OP's question.

Comment: wouldn't that be the same as `theStaticClass = {A:7}`. There's nothing static about that, I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

This is another (I wouldn't say less ugly) way, but now `TheStaticClass.A` is more like a getter method (the advantage being that it also works in IE):

```
var TheStaticClass = new (function() {
  var a=1;
  arguments.callee.prototype.A = function() {
    return a;
  };
})();

alert(TheStaticClass.A()) //=> 1
```

Comment: There are [some issues](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs) with named function expressions in IE.

Comment: That's why I changed it to `arguments.callee` within an anonymous function. New! Even uglier still!

Comment: Obviously, I didn't see that change at the moment I wrote my comment. Your new function will even trigger an exception when someone bluntly puts `"use strict";` in their code.

Comment: But then again `use strict` isn't usable in IE either ;)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you need to do some modifications to the variable before returning:

```
var theStaticClass = (function () {
    var a = 7;
    return {A: (function(b){
        return b * b;
    })(a)};
})();
console.log(theStaticClass.A); // => 49
```