# Dynamic JavaScript object property value

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, jscript

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to have an object property defined in its prototype as a dynamic value that can change every time an instance of the object is created.  That's kind of the best way I can describe it; I have made a fiddle to show what I'm trying to do (though it doesn't work).

```
var Response = {
    LCID: 321
};


Date.prototype.LCID = Number(0);
Date.prototype.LCID.valueOf = function() { return Response.LCID; };


document.write((new Date()).LCID);
Response.LCID = 456;
document.write((new Date()).LCID);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tx2fW/2/

What I'm trying to achieve is that `Response.LCID` can change over the lifetime of the code as you can see from me changing its value in the code later on.  Whenever I create a `Date` object, I want the value of `(new Date()).LCID` to be the current value of `Response.LCID`, not just the value that it had when I first create `Date.prototype.LCID`.

Is there any way this can be done?  The biggest limitation is that it has to work in JavaScript 1.5... though I would be curious to see if it could be done in recent versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and experimenting, I was able to actually solve the issue.  I had tried playing with the Date constructor and such, but I didn't have much luck in my initial trials - apparently because I overlooked the fact that the Date object is unique in that it differs in functionality depending on how it is called (as a function or object constructor).  This means that you can't just do `Date.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments)` since all you'll ever get back is a string (the Date object is being called as a function).

After having found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181348/instantiating-a-javascript-object-by-calling-prototype-constructor-apply) and reading it, I came up with the following code that creates an actual Date object (or string if called as a function) and mimics the built-in Date object perfectly (as far as my tests show anyways).  Every time a new Date object is created, it gets the LCID property which is dynamically generated during object creation which is exactly what I needed.

```
Date = (function(orig) {
    var date = function(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
        var object = (this instanceof Object ? (arguments.length < 1 ? new orig() : (arguments.length < 2 ? new orig(a) : (arguments.length < 4 ? new orig(a, b || 0, c || 1) : new orig(a, b, c, d || 0, e || 0, f || 0, g || 0)))) : orig());
        object.LCID = Response.LCID;

        return object;
    };
    date.prototype = orig.prototype;

    return date;
})(Date);
```

I also created a bunch of test cases to ensure that there is no difference from a built-in Date object, or using this code (comment out this code to see the results using the built-in Date object and compare).

```
var Response = { 'LCID': 123 };


Date = (function(orig) {
    var date = function(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
        var object = (this instanceof Object ? (arguments.length < 1 ? new orig() : (arguments.length < 2 ? new orig(a) : (arguments.length < 4 ? new orig(a, b || 0, c || 1) : new orig(a, b, c, d || 0, e || 0, f || 0, g || 0)))) : orig());
        object.LCID = Response.LCID;
        return object;
    };
    date.prototype = orig.prototype;
    return date;
})(Date);


var x = new Date();
document.writeln(x);
document.writeln(x.LCID);
document.writeln(x.getFullYear());
document.writeln(typeof x);
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(x));
document.writeln(x instanceof Date);
document.writeln("<br/>");

Response.LCID = 456;

var y = new Date();
document.writeln(y);
document.writeln(y.LCID);
document.writeln(y.getFullYear());
document.writeln(typeof y);
document.writeln(Object.prototype.toString.call(y));
document.writeln(y instanceof Date);
document.writeln("<br/>");

document.writeln(Date());
document.writeln(new Date());
document.writeln(new Date(2012));
document.writeln(new Date(2012, 7));
document.writeln(new Date(2012, 7, 14));
document.writeln(new Date(2012, 7, 14, 9));
document.writeln(new Date(2012, 7, 14, 9, 45));
document.writeln(new Date(2012, 7, 14, 9, 45, 27));
document.writeln(new Date(2012, 7, 14, 9, 45, 27, 687));
```

This is also available as an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tx2fW/9/

Answer (score 1):

Ok this does it using the [`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/DefineGetter) method, however I am not sure how it will behave on all browser but that the only way I could find to achieve what you want (well I think this time it is what you want)

http://jsfiddle.net/tx2fW/6/ working example.

```
var Response = {
    LCID: 321
};

var d = Date.prototype;

d._LCID = Number(0);
d.getLCID = function() {
    if (d._LCID != Response.LCID) d._LCID = Response.LCID;
    return d._LCID ;
};
d.__defineGetter__("LCID", function() {
    return this.getLCID();
});

document.write((new Date()).LCID);
Response.LCID = 456;
document.write((new Date()).LCID);​
```

For alternative to `__defineGetter__` please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731454/neat-alternatives-to-definegetter)

Comment: No, I specifically want Response.LCID to change and have it's change reflected in new Date objects.  I do not want to have to change `Date.prototype.LCID`.

Comment: Need your own wrapper for Date then, otherwise what you ask can't be done http://jsfiddle.net/tx2fW/4/

Comment: Using a custom date object is also not an option unfortunately.  What I'm trying to ultimately achieve is being able to attach locale ID's to objects, either built-in objects or custom objects.  If I can't do it for built-in objects, the point is lost since I would have to get other programmers to be aware of all the custom objects to use instead of built-ins.

Comment: Yeah I see what you are trying to achieve. The only way that could be done is by modifying the Date object constructor I guess but I don't think you can do that in JS (need to play with it and see). As that way it would set its own value on creation.

Comment: Internet Explorer JScript doesn't support `__defineGetter__`.

Comment: I know this is a couple years old but __defineGetter__ is deprecated. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

`Number(0) === 0`. Modifying `.valueOf` and `.toString` on primitive values have no effect.

The correct way to do this is to pass an **instance of** the `Number` constructor, using the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

```
var Response = {
    LCID: 321
};
Date.prototype.LCID = new Number();   // <-- Use the "new" operator
Date.prototype.LCID.valueOf = function() { return Response.LCID; };
```

### Annotated demo and notes: http://jsfiddle.net/tx2fW/7/

- `LCID` is an object. **`typeof new Date().LCID === 'object'`**.
- `LCID` is a true instance of `Number`. **`new Date().LCID instanceof Number === true`**
- `LCID` is equal to 321: **`(new Date().LCID == 321) === true`**
- `LCID` is not identical to 321: **`(new Date().LCID === 321) === false`**.
  (because LCID is an object, and 321 is a primitive number value).

PS. If you're not familiar with `==` versus `===`, see [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Comment: +1 for getting the answer right and posting the code here. But no one should mess with built–in prototypes. Seems you got a drive–by -1.

Comment: @RobG About modifying prototypes: He did not elaborate his application, so I cannot judge whether his decision is OK or not. Rule of thumb: Does the added property directly relate to the `Date` constructor? If not: Do not extend the prototype.

Comment: Thank you for this - I had actually tried that before and kept trying other ways because your code fails if JavaScript doesn't have to cast/coerce the LCID property in to another type.  Your code only works because it's being converted to a string for concatenation.  Try outputting **just** `(new Date()).LCID` to see what happens (you get a zero).

Comment: @EliSand I explained that in my annotations: It is an object. One character can make the method to behave as expected, across all (ancient) browsers: `+(new Date).LCID` (notice the unary `+`), see also point **s and t of [Comparison between all number-conversion methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8112802/938089?are-there-are-any-side-effects-of-using-this-method-to-convert-a-string-to-an-in)**.

Comment: Oh, and fully aware of == and ===, as well as when and why to extend an objects prototype.  This properly does directly relate to the object; I'm creating a locale ID for Date objects.  This is for server-side JavaScript in Classic ASP (`Response.LCID` is an ASP object).